# scapy sniffing only packets on my computer & filter for http packets needed

Tags: python, http, scapy, packet-sniffers, sniffing

I'm working on a project in which I sniff http packets that go through my network,
but scapy sniffs only packets that are sent to my computer or broadcasted.

I saw that there is a parameter called `iface` for the sniffing function-

`sniff(iface= ? )`

Yet, I find no documentation or explanation about it online. 
Can someone explain how it can help and what value to put in it when sniffing if I want to sniff the whole network and not just my computer?

Also I don't find a filter function for http packets, so I'd appreciate it if someone could write it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some documentation on [sniffing](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#sniffing) for Scapy. There is also some information regarding [filters](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#filters) but it's quite sparse.

More than likely you will be able to use something like the following:
`sniff(iface="eth0", filter="tcp and port 80")` to get the `HTTP` packets. Obviously the actual interface will be different based on the names of the interfaces on your machine.

Comment: Section 8.2.1 of [this](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf) is also useful.

Comment: how can I check  whats the interfaces names on my machine?